# How can I create a CCombo in SWT that changes based on the value of another CCombo?

Tags: java, swt, windowbuilder

I have 1 CCombo, or drop down menu, that contains item types such as `"Shoes", "Shirts", "Pants"` and I want a second CCombo to change its contents based on what the first one has selected. For example, if `Shirts` is selected, I want the second CCombo to be `"Small", "Medium", "Large"`, but if `Shoes` is selected, I want the second CCombo to be `"8", "9", "10"`. For the first CCombo, I have the following block of code:

```
final CCombo combo_2 = new CCombo(composite, SWT.BORDER);
combo_2.setToolTipText("");
combo_2.setListVisible(true);
combo_2.setItems(new String[] {"Shoes","Pants","Shirt"});
combo_2.setEditable(false);
combo_2.setBounds(57, 125, 109, 21);
combo_2.setText("Type");
combo_2.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        String typex = combo_2.getText();
        System.out.println("Type: "+ typex +" selected");
    }});
```

This listens and prints whenever the item type is changed. The for the second CCombo, I have this block of code:

```
    final CCombo combo_1 = new CCombo(composite, SWT.BORDER);
combo_1.setToolTipText("");
combo_1.setListVisible(true);
combo_1.setItems(new String[] {"Small","Medium","Large"});
combo_1.setEditable(false);
combo_1.setBounds(57, 208, 109, 21);
combo_1.setText("Size");
combo_1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        String typey = combo_1.getText();
        System.out.println("Size "+typey+" selected");
    }});
```

When I try and get the value of `typex` in the block of the second CCombo, Ecipse says `"typex cannot be resolved to a variable"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `typex` and `typey` within the `Listener`, consequently, they are only valid in said listener. This is because their [*scope*](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) is limited to the method they're defined in (`widgetSelected()`).

There are two things you could do:

1. Define `typex` and `typey` as fields of your class. Then they will be accessible from any non-`static` method in your class.
2. Define your listeners like this:

```
new SelectionAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
    {
        String typex = combo_2.getText();
        String typey = combo_1.getText();
        System.out.println(typex + " " + typey);
    }
}
```

---

BTW: Don't use `setBounds` unless you really have to. Use a layout instead. This article should be helpful:

[Understanding Layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html)